# Unable to migrate the database from SQL Server to Azure SQL

Tags: sql-server, azure, migrate, dma

I am getting the below error while migrating a SQL Server database to Azure using dma

> An unexpected error occurred.
>
> Failed to migrate data from source database 'AdventureWorks2019' to target database 'databasemigrate'.
>
> The pipeline failed to write a data range batch for table databasemigrate.Person.Address.
>
> The pipeline failed to write a batch to table databasemigrate.Person.Address. The SQL query was SELECT   "AddressID",
> "AddressLine1",
> "AddressLine2",
> "City",
> "StateProvinceID",
> "PostalCode",
> "SpatialLocation",
> "rowguid",
> "ModifiedDate"
> FROM     "AdventureWorks2019"."Person"."Address"
> ORDER BY "AddressID" ASC
> Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.Type'.

I am trying to migrate the database to Azure using DMA, but I am getting that error.

Comment: There is a mismatch in the nullable types, are you sure the schema is exactly the same where you are trying to export?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have some null data which is not allowed by your target DB's schema.

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.Type'.
```

I believe this can be fixed by sanitizing your source data to not have nulls or just allowing null data for target DB's table schema.

**1st option:** Sanitize your data. For this you can update the null data with T-SQL query.

Image a table like this:

[image]

You may update null values to empty strings like this:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[SampleTable]
   SET [SomeText] = ''
WHERE [SomeText] is null
```

Result will be like this:

[image]

Also you can prefer some predefined text instead of empty string to find the updated data in case you need later.

**2nd option:** Allow nulls. I do not have azure right now. For that reason I cannot send screen shot of that. But I believe there must some kind of similar option for that DB too.

[image]

Hope one of these solutions help.

Comment: How to allow null data for target DB’s  table schema. Could you help me with steps are solution

Comment: Updated answer to have sample steps. Hope this helps. @PunithKM 
If helps please do not forget to mark as answer.